# Can I Undo Netbeans Refactoring (Rename Variable) Function?

Tags: netbeans, ide, logging, automated-refactoring

So I wasn't paying careful attention when using the the Refactor->Rename function in Netbeans a few times this morning and now I'm afraid Netbeans may have automatically changed the names of some variables I didn't intend to change. Is there any way to go back and check a log or something to see what variables Netbeans affected?

Comment: 1) use version control system 1A) try searching in Local History in Netbeans 2) `Ctrl+Z` should do the trick most of the time, when you immediately want to cancel rename refactoring.

Comment: @c69: +1 for recommending a version control system!

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think about just busting an "svn st" to check until after I posted this. Thanks. You should actually write an answer so you can get credit.

Comment: I have the same problem.  1) no version control.  1A) I made more edits so local history will revert too much.  2) CTRL-Z does nothing at all, unlike in Eclipse. I'm using Netbeans 7.0.1